# Can't connect to azure bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, azureportal

I have an Azure bot that I'm trying to connect to and it keeps giving me 401 errors. I have checked my App ID and password to no end they are exactly the same in my code as they are in the Azure portal. Azure seems to have removed all of my channels in the Portal and will not allow me to re-add them. Is anyone else having this issue or is it just me? Any solutions?

Here is another question I posted in the azure help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/617004/can39t-connect-to-bot.html

Comment: http 401 is a client side authentication error. So either your identity is wrong or the url that you are using is not correct

Comment: ok, but why does the Azure portal keep deleting my channels? I know everything is correct as far as my URLs because I'm getting through to my code running locally. I know my app id and keys are correct because I copied and pasted them directly from the azure portal.

Comment: can you share the error log?

Comment: It just tells me 401 ERROR
 Error: Unauthorized. Invalid AppId passed on token. I've checked my app ID and password about 1000 times so I'm not quite sure what else to check

Comment: It looks like this has happened before: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2b6e1d5b-bce7-478c-94a2-9eeb392f4fee/cant-create-web-app-bot-from-azure-portal?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

This is exactly what is happening to me

Comment: @SamRedmond try to verify one more scenario, Please check your appid and password in application app settings and azure app service configuration section. If both are the same then you are facing a different issue. Otherwise, handle the scenario in a different manner.

Comment: I would recommend you log an issue with Azure and/or post the issue in the [azure-bot-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-bot-service.html?filter=unanswered) docs forum for support. I think the issue you are experiencing is specific to Azure; you should be working with their team to resolve what is happening.